# Git app that creates libraries from a subset of a project

Tags: git

Is there a git application (ui that generates editable data configuration or I suppose command line working) that allows you to select a subset of files to publish as a git project? The use case for this being:

Let's say you have your main shared library under a src directory. It would be greatly beneficial to be able to manage this src directory internally as a single repository while being able to publish a sub package/module located in said directory publicly. Copying and managing the applicable commits to this subset of available classes would be a huge pain.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: It almost sounds like you want submodules; it almost sounds like you want that as its own standalone project (Maven + POMs).  Could you illustrate it a bit better?  Where the project lives is immaterial; if it's referenced or necessary by other projects is *much* more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)?  This lets you collect multiple repositories together into a single directory tree, and is often used in the case where you are managing separate libraries/modules as a separate project. [Some people think](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/) that submodules are problematic to manage.

The [git subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) project is an alternative take on this that may also meet your needs.